# Nifi - How to insert XML whole content into JSON attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to insert the whole content of a row of an XML file into a JSON attribute (I am a newbie).

I am doing it this way (tell me if there is an easier way, it's good to now):

[image]

I have configured Extract text this way:

[image]

And to finish, I configure the Replace Text, giving a JSON format:

[image]

But he result appears to be wrong (doesn't work like a normal JSON file, for example if I a try to do a httpPost):

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are concern regards to `new lines` and `json key/values` then use [NiFi expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) functions on the extracted attribute(`data`).

**ReplaceText Configs:**

[image]
**Replacement value:**

```
{"name" : "user1","time" : "${now()}","data" : "${data:replaceAll('\s',''):escapeJson()}"}
```

Use **escapeJson** and **replaceAll** function to replace all spaces,newlines with `''`
Replacement Strategy as `Always Replace`

**(or)**

Another way of preparing json message is by using **AttributesToJson** processor.
if we are using this processor then we **need to prepare attributes/values** before AttributesToJson processor by using **UpdateAttribute** processor

**Flow**:

```
1.SplitXml
2.ExtractText //add data property to extract content to flowfile attribute
3.UpdateAttribute //add name property -> user1 
                    add time property -> ${now()} 
                    add data property -> ${data:replaceAll('\s',''):escapeJson()}}
4.AttributeToJson //Attributes List -> name,time,data
                    Destination     -> flowfile content
                    include core attributes -> false
```

Comment: Thanks! I think the second option will be more smart solution :)

Comment: The result is better, but now is appearing a lot of '/' in the xml part. How can I fix this? :<?xmlversion=\\\"1.0\\\"encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"?><row><FIELD1>1<\\/FIELD1>....

Comment: @jmarco10, Use **unescapeJson()** to remove all extra '\' in xml part and if these extra '\' are coming randomly then use ifElse statement and check if the attribute value contains '\' then apply **unescapeJson()** else apply **escapeJson()** function. (or) if this doesn't work use **ReplaceText** processor and search for '\' **literal** and **replace with empty string**. https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#ifelse